# Python: KeyError but both key and value exists

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, api

I'm fetching information from the opendota API. I've previously taken out a .csv list with approx. 160 match_ids which I want some more information from and then append certain values to a list.

With the code below, While looping through the list I receive a KeyError.

```
for x in finallist:
    matchinfo = requests.get("https://api.opendota.com/api/matches/{}".format(x)).json()["match_id"]
    print(matchinfo)
```

The KeyError is raised on a certain ID's, but if I use the code below, I get no KeyError and I see the information.

```
matchspec = requests.get("https://api.opendota.com/api/matches/4184421518").json()['match_id']
matchspec
```

So through this, 4184421518 prints information, but in the loop it stops at that ID and a couple more IDs below that. Why do I receive a KeyError in the for loop, but not when I specifically ask for the information?

Comment: I think u need to add the positional argument in {}. For example it should be : matchinfo = requests.get("https://api.opendota.com/api/matches/{0}".format(str(x))).json()["match_id"]

Comment: Opendota api is rate limited to 60 requests/min. Make sure you are not exceeding that, as it seems like an error with the api response.

Comment: Your solution did not work, but I added the {0} in my code and it looped through more IDs but ultimately returned a KeyError prior to finishing the list.

Comment: @ShivamSingh This seems to be the cause that raises the KeyError!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Opendota api is rate limited to 60 requests/min. Make sure you are not exceeding that, as it seems like an error with the api response.